# Why Sql*plus was invoked when the application is running

Tags: vb.net, oracle, sqlplus

Today I have received an email from clients who are testing our windows application. There is the question:"Sql*plus was also invoked during the testing activities. Is this executed from within the application?" I'm not a DBA so I have no answer. We don't call such execution within the application and the only thing I can assume that since we have a connection string to Oracle DB it can somehow be invoked during the connection to DB because sqlplus is a part of Oracle. Maybe it happens during the validation of credentials?
Could you please give me the clear answer?
Thank you in advance

Comment: SQL*Plus is merely an Oracle utility. It won't automatically invoke just from connecting. As a first step, I'd suggest clarifying what the client said - a confused bug report from a client is *way* more likely than SQL*Plus just invoking out of nowhere. If you're convinced after that that SQL*Plus is just popping up, then something somewhere is specifically invoking it. Search your code base for any references to "sqlplus".

Answer (score 2):

One can only speculate, but I'd bet that somewhere in your application a developer couldn't figure out how to do something via the ODBC/OLEDB driver and instead opted to execute a sql script by starting a sqlplus.exe process and feeding it command-line parameters. They probably forgot to set up the ProcessStartInfo so that UseShellExecute and CreateNoWindow are both set to false.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense because in our development we have no such a problem and deployment  on test has been done by clients.